# SQL help - if then else (match on one criteria, else match on another)

Tags: sql

I need to return an ACCOUNT_ID if it matches a 3RD_PARTY_ID.
If there isn't a match, I want to make another attempt to match it on email address instead.

ACCOUNT_TABLE

| ACCOUNT_ID | 3RD_PARTY_ID | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | AAA |  |
| 002 |  | bob@bob.com |

MATCHING_TABLE

| MATCH_# | MATCH_3RD_ID | MATCH_EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| zz1 | AAA | jan@jan.com |
| zz2 | ZZZ | bob@bob.com |
| zz3 | QQQ | nan@nan.com |

My objective is a query like:

```
   select 
    From ACCOUNT_TABLE AT
       IF AT.3RD_PARTY_ID = MATCHING_TABLE.3RD_PARTY_ID
       Else IF AT.EMAIL   = MATCHING_TABLE.EMAIL
```

Desired end result:

| MATCH_# | ACCOUNT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| zz1 | 001 |
| zz2 | 002 |
| zz3 |  |

Thanks and help help would be awesome!
Geoff

Comment: tag which dbms you're using please

Answer (score 2):

Use two `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select at.*, coalesce(mt3.match_no, mte.match_no) as match_no
from ACCOUNT_TABLE at left join
     MATCHING_TABLE mt3
     ON at.3RD_PARTY_ID = mt3.MATCH_3RD_ID left join
     MATCHING_TABLE mt3
     ON at.EMAIL = mt.MATCH_EMAIL AND mt3.MATCH_3RD_ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select * 
from MATCHING_TABLE mt
left join ACCOUNT_TABLE at
 on at.3RD_PARTY_ID = mt.MATCH_3RD_ID
 or at.EMAIL = mt.MATCH_EMAIL
```

Comment: @GeoffGarcia . . . This does not apply the logic "if the first does not match, match the second".  It will match both, perhaps creating duplicate rows in the result set (not for your provided data though).

Answer (score 0):

You can use join...

```
SELECT M.MATCH_#, A.ACCOUNT_ID
FROM ACCOUNT_TABLE A
RIGHT JOIN MATCHING_TABLE M ON (M.MATCH_THIRD_ID = A.THIRD_PARTY_ID OR M.MATCH_EMAIL = A.EMAIL)
-- WHERE ISNULL(M.MATCH_#,'') <> '' -- Uncomment this line to retrieve only matching records
```